# XQuery: Using xs:time($arg) vs cast as xs:time

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, saxon, xquery-3.0

In one of my projects I'm using

- XQuery 3.0
- Saxon HE 9.8 (transitive because of Camel)
- Spring Boot 2.1.0
- Apache Camel 2.22.0

I consume a XML message in which the following element occurs:
`<mytimeelement></mytimeelement>`

As you can see it is empty so I thought that the following XQuery-Expression would return an **empty sequence**:

`$transaction/*:flags/*:mytimeelement`

Unfortunately this seems not to be the case because calling the XQuery-Expression from above in an `xs:time($arg)` like:

`xs:time($transaction/*:flags/*:mytimeelement)`

does not return an empty sequence as I would have expected but instead returns an exception:

`Invalid time "" (too short)`

The thing is: I want to use the `xs:time($arg)` as validation that if a value is in the element it has to have the correct format, but if it's empty it doesn't matter. So I did this not only with `xs:time` but also with `xs:date` and `xs:decimal`.

My question now is: Why is the expression not returning an empty sequence but an empty string? Or should I better use a `cast as xs:time` instead?

Comment: Why would a path like `$transaction/*:flags/*:mytimeelement` selecting `mytimeelement` elements select an empty sequence if such an element exists? You would need to add a predicate `$transaction/*:flags/*:mytimeelement[normalize-space()]` to select an empty sequence if the element contains only white space or nothing. Of couse you can also try a cast `$transaction/*:flags/*:mytimeelement[. castable as xs:time]` if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes you're absolute right. I guess I was missing the forest through the trees. Thanks a lot for the answer